# React 18 [MainLayoutRoute] is not a <Route> component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use the `MainLayout component` to add the **Navbar** to the required pages and redirect the user to the login page if he's not logged in.

However now since I updated to `react 18` and Component in `Route` was replaced by element. this  part is no longer working and threw an error

```
Uncaught Error: [MainLayoutRoute] is not a <Route> component.
All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment
```

```js
const MainLayoutRoute = ({ path, component: Component, render, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      path={path}
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        if (!auth.BasicAuth())
          return (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: "/login",
                state: { from: props.location },
              }}
            />
          );
        return Component ? (
          <>
            <Navbar />
            <Component {...props} />
          </>
        ) : (
          render(props)
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A Route component is used in React applications to define a path that the app should respond to. When the app’s URL matches the path specified by the Route, the component that is associated with that route will be rendered. This allows developers to create dynamic, single-page applications that can render different content based on the current URL.

On the other hand, MainLayoutRoute is not a Route component. It is a component that is used to wrap other components and provide them with a common layout. This is useful when building applications with multiple pages, as it allows the developer to define a consistent layout that can be applied to all pages.
Find more info here - https://moderncodr.com/react-18-mainlayoutroute-is-not-a-route-component/

Comment: The problem is with the new react version this kind of approach no longer work.